# Why won't my EOS M5 take a photo in SCN/HDR mode with a manual lens?

Tags: shutter, error, shooting-mode, canon-m

Sometimes I press the shutter button of my Eos M5 and it **just. won't. take. a. photo.**

I know there are some 'obvious' reasons for the camera to refuse taking a picture, like having not enough light for the AF to work.

Right now I have a manual Samyang lens mounted configured in SCN/HDR mode and when I try to take a picture and this damn camera won't let me..

In fact currently only `P`/`M`/`Av` and `Tv` modes let me take pictures.

I've searched all the menu several times now in the hope to find some funny configuration like the shutter button being deactivated by some troll - but without luck.

What are the preconditions for taking pictures I have to check in doubt?

- Light is OK - for testing purposes I try to take a picture of my bright monitor - half-trigger configures 1/250 at ISO 100
- Aperture is manually set to 1.4
- Lens generally works on this camera (`P`/`M`/`Av`/`Tv` modes work fine)
- Take photo w/o lens is enabled where possible

What else should I check?

The `C.Fn.` tab in the menu is not available for the modes I can't take pictures in. So maybe shooting w/o lens is disabled there. Might that be possible? What could be the reason for this?!

Comment: Scene modes normally means the camera is controlling aperture and it can't do that with a manual lens.  Haven't any direct experience of the M5, but that'd be my guess.

Comment: I'm surprised that lens works in any exposure mode other than *Manual* exposure mode. Are you sure the lens isn't communicating anything at all to the camera?

Answer (score 1):

The scene modes require the camera to be able to communicate with the lens. If the camera doesn't detect a lens it won't release the shutter in the scene modes.

Answer (score 1):

Only M and Av modes should actually work with a manual lens. P and Tv shouldn't, since those might require aperture adjustment. If you have a chipped adapter, there might be a problem in terms of how the chip fakes being an EOS lens; the camera may be expecting some communication that the lens/chip isn't capable of sending (e.g., focus distance or something).